# How to configure a compiler in qmake

Tags: c++, qt

I am having issues configuring my qmake project to build/compile the same way as a command in the console. The working command to compile from console is:

g++ main.cpp -std=c++11 -luWS -lz -lssl

The flags are necessary to resolve some undefined references. Now I set up my .pro-file as follows

```
QT += core
QT -= gui
TARGET = car_mpc_ex
CONFIG += console
CONFIG -= app_bundle
QMAKE_CXXFLAGS += -std=c++11
QMAKE_CXXFLAGS += -luWS
QMAKE_CXXFLAGS += -lz
QMAKE_CXXFLAGS += -lssl
SOURCES +=
    main.cpp
    [...]
DISTFILES +=

HEADERS +=
    [...]
```

Rebuild all in QT Creator and the undefined references, solved when building in the console, are not solved... Somehow my flags are ignored?

Comment: Check the flags that Qt Creator used in the Compile Output tab and compare with the working flags.

Comment: Note that the question has nothing to do with Qt Creator. You're dealing with qmake.

Answer (score 2):

`QMAKE_CXXFLAGS` is used for compiler flags whereas the libraries should be specified as linker flags. This is done through the [`LIBS`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmake-variable-reference.html#libs) variable (or the equivalent with the `QMAKE_` prefix `QMAKE_LIBS` that you shouldn't need to use).

Also, the C++11 option has to be specified for both the compiler and the linker, but you can use qmake [`CONFIG`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmake-variable-reference.html#config) variable to handle it in a more portable way:

```
CONFIG += c++11
```